# Change Azure VM authentication to ssh key

Tags: azure, azure-linux

I have Linux VM on Azure which at first set without SSH keys. which means authentication is made only with password via SSH. I would like to change it now. I tried the way I know, I can login with the keys - but still login with password.

What else did I miss? There is something else?

Thanks

Tried to configure SSH key, disable the 'passwordauthentication'

Change ssh config
Add key via azure portal

Comment: I too had this same problem and it turned out that my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file was including all config files within the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d` folder too. Looking in that folder, there was a file called `50-cloud-init.conf` which I assume was created by Azure itself and this file contained a single line of `PasswordAuthentication yes`, overriding the setting in the main config file. Deleting that file and restarting the ssh service fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to following these steps -

1. Login to your existing azure VM using passwords authentication.
2. Create new ssh key pair.

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
3. Replace `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` key

   mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
4. Save `~/.ssh/id_rsa` public key to your local system.
5. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make following changes

   ###### Change PasswordAuthentication to this:

   PasswordAuthentication no

   ###### Change PubkeyAuthentication to this:

   PubkeyAuthentication yes

   ###### Change PermitRootLogin to this:

   PermitRootLogin no

   ###### Change ChallengeResponseAuthentication to this:

   ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
6. Restart the vm using following command

   sudo systemctl restart ssh

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I have created Linux VM on Azure first set without SSH keys only with password via SSH then I tried to authentication to ssh key like below:

Create SSH key pair:

**`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`**

Then, use **`/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`**

Enter passphrase: Give your password

Once you enter password RSA will executed successfully like below:

[image]

Then try to move to id_rsa to authorized using below script:

```
`mv/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys`
```

[image]

when I run this cmd **`cat id_rsa`** I got public key successfully like below

[image]

I agree with *schine som* And save public key open config file with ***vi*** and try restart like below:

**`PasswordAuthentication no`**

[image]

**`PubkeyAuthentication yes`**

[image]
**`PermitRootLogin no`**

[image]

**`ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`**

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I did all these step before, i can login using SSH, but im also still able to login with password.

Comment: Kindly check this doc https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-with-key#:~:text=Public%20Key%20Authentication%20is%20a,strength%20and%20automated%20passwordless%20logins for more info

Comment: @GalAvichid I too had this same problem and it turned out that my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file was including all config files within the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d` folder too.  Looking in that folder, there was a file called `50-cloud-init.conf` which I assume was created by Azure itself and this file contained a single line of `PasswordAuthentication yes`, overriding the setting in the main config file.  Deleting that file and restarting the ssh service fixed the problem.